# не устанавливается python на windows 10 ошибка 0х80070661

Tags: python

Не устанавливается python на windows 10 ошибка 0х80070661. Говорит что не поддерживает процесор

Comment: Ну может и правда не поддерживает процессор?

Comment: С подобные проблемы бывают в "сборках" винды.  И еще если у вас 32 битная win то и инсталлятор должен быть 32, для 64 аналогично